# Steps for installing Orbfit 4.2

Tags: installation

I'm trying to install Orbfit4.2 on a using linux mint maya edition. I'm trying to follow the on line help.  I have unzipped the tared file, configured with $ ./config -0 gfortran and then  $ make.  Both  appears to be successful. I am now trying to create the DE405 data files in the /orbfit/src/jpleph directory.  I have downloaded the header.405 and the ascp*date* ascii files into the directory from JPL.  I have run $ make ephemerides and get the following;

```
cat header.405 ascp1960.405 ascp1980.405 ascp2000.405 ascp2020.405> input.430
asc2eph.x < input.430
/bin/sh: 1: asc2eph.x: not found
make: *** [ephemerides] Error 127
```

(I have also used input value of 405 instead of 430)

I have also tried just running from with in

the directory
  $ ./asc2eph.x  which was the previous method before the Makefile was included.  All I get with  this is  'authors' introductory message and the flashing working box-still running 6 hrs later.

If anybody has any experience or advice with installing Orbfit 4.2 from the start or can help me move on from the above blockage I would appreciate.

Note I am a real novice and would appreciate idiot step by step guide- I'm the idiot.

Eric

Answer (score 0):

The Makefile assumes that the current directory "." is in your path. This is a security risk. You can either edit the Makefile to rename these binaries:

```
$ diff -u Makefile.orig Makefile
--- Makefile.orig   2014-01-09 07:14:10.000000000 -0800
+++ Makefile    2014-10-21 11:40:00.850236839 -0700
@@ -10,7 +10,7 @@
    make clean

 ephemerides: input asc2eph.x
-   asc2eph.x < input.430
+   ./asc2eph.x < input.430
    mv JPLEPH jpleph
    make clean
```

Or you can add . to your path (but this is insecure!) by doing

```
$ PATH=.:$PATH
```